# How to save the image automatically when using camera intent from my app?

Tags: android, android-camera

when i am using camera intent from my app then it is opening camera but after clicking it asks to save the image but when we click image using mobile camera app it saves automatically.

Using camera intent also opens the same inbuild camera app then why thid dual behaviour?

Also how to make the camera to save the image automatically when using camera intent from my app

Comment: where you want it to be saved ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    //Get Image from Camera
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CLICK_RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        dialog2.dismiss();
        Bitmap photo = null;
        try {
            photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                    getContentResolver(), imageUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        selectedImage = getResizedBitmap(photo, 900)


        try {
            //Write file
            filename = "your file name.extension";
            File file = new File("Directory path where you want to save");
            file.mkdir();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file + filename);
            selectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);

            //Cleanup
            fileOutputStream.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
}

//Resize Bitmap
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    float bitmapRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
    if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
        width = maxSize;
        height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
    } else {
        height = maxSize;
        width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
    }
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
}
```